# Ploting a Factor with Ggplot2 and sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Why ploting a factors returns a grid of results?

Create a map

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = hexagons_with_lines, aes(fill = component), color = NA) +  # Remove stroke
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(fill = "Component", title = "Map of Hexagons with Line Components")
```

The Data

[Variables of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im9xP.png)

typeof(hexagons_with_lines$component)

[1] "integer"
unique(hexagons_with_lines$component)

[1]     7    10  3231  3226  6844   739    18  2359    41   600    89  1650  1835   392  1517   113  1076
[18]  2671   110    30  2244  2764   240  1532  2989  1049  1221  1052  2661  1413  2005  1817     1  1779
[35]  2126  1017    14  1022   340   662   377   940  1562  1219     5  2186  1171     3   343   334    16
[52]  5257    76  1331  5578  3248  1305  1739 16152  7554   170  7887  4858  4849  3242  5263    67  4546
[69] 20629  3972   323  1102  7516 17092   285  4684  4354  3614  3188  6043    95  7987  4617  4624  4348
[86]  3191    32  3852  4582  4243  5018    55  5073  3610  2266  3438  1494  6516 15210   508  2563  3086
[103]  6316  3396  1496  5395    26  4341  6574 19298  8898 10177  3555  6396  6546  5214  8725  3140  6786
[120]  3404  3495   942  7818  4439  6629  6728   162  8487  4160  5904  8863  3719  3685  3691  3152  3041
[137]  3529   876  3456  5230  6956  4806  2111  3716  3787 14904   287  6143  6142 18455  5352  6625   506
[154]  7375  6599  6617  6621  5604  5492  6010  5671  3744  6791  8059  4031  1571  3558  3559  2102  4622
[171]  5820  7260  5771  6078  7217  4692  4697  4590  4571 13637  5429  8491  4701  4707   647  6032    78
[188]  4201  6609  7373  7729  1214  2831  1097  6284   882  6538  8580    63  6637  6915  5248  4670  4626
[205]  6025  7042  5166  6680  3530 18457  1529  6741 14290  8505  3838  7104    37  2346  5741  6535  6436
[222] 14895  3298  7109  3647  5137  5146  5010  7766  3957  8720  6562  5891   724   332  9553  4997  5605
[239]  2524  4703  4658  5851  5314  5318  7405  8493  4545  6272  6745 10265  7362  6376  8703  7462 17684
[256] 15006  6176  7823  4874  8819 16715 11178  5674  3817  7622  1714  1716  6970  4816 16365  4018  5688
[273]  9301  5837  6066  8408  5345  7410 11069  6120  6672  4714   160 19878  4610  5888  3580  3633   262
[290]  5015  6691  5031  4538  5988  7282  3026  6249  7050  1619  8401 16419  7355   825  8451  7834  8218
[307] 15212  7868  4325  5188  6891  6894   874  4779  9444 18825  5505  3505  3222  9243  4892  6628  6729
[324]  4384  4246  8244  7991  8174  5913  7522  7307  8834  6815  6796  3812 10650  6912   218  3640  3590
[341] 16872  6940  8222  8530  4685  9382  3071  8858  8860  8952  8995  6236 18612  4531  5862   415  8297
[358] 14501  8521  7532  3159  6858  9724    35  3813  5989  1548  8996  8217  5059  6042  8466  4268   428
[375]  4315  7781 14954  6610  5413  4435  4710  4309  1899  5592  9082  3893 15656  1766  9575  2019  7054
[392]  5171    87 10631  4541  5095  7101   938  2365  3549  1407  9657  6027  5666  8539  5729  5853  5857
[409]   257  2361  2363  5821  8331  8598  5350  5926  7067   216  4294  9734  6006  7448  7450  5035  5064
[426]  4458  4457  6595  8964  6744  9608  3820  8040 16910  3025  3862  4316 19637  4313  1718  1598  7502
[443]  4378    47  9713 10680 13378  7124  4765  9401  4296  7980  9224  6186  8016  4986  7030  8484  2555
[460]  5463  7684  7538  4373  7671 11170  7779  8002  7204  2035  6181  4140  2158  6724  5545  5521  4578
[477]  9040  5490  4717  7510  6014  7753  6300  4742  3805  6816  8507   115 15846  7600  3028  7285   266
[494] 17872 17874  7616  5530  5409  6177  9195  7118  6454  6460  5585  6739  9307  5914  8315   658  4998
[511]  1636   732  1370  7061 19857  6318  3372  3877  7526  8843  8845   386  9396  9660 16014  4778  6001
[528]  3919  9661  7396  3806  7027  3098  1580  9255  6569  9097  3442  5842  6835   620  7902  6393  6144
[545]  7687  4737 15881  8289  1897  6499  9122   253  9596  5341  7896  6973  6365  5232  8418  2784  3105
[562]  8381  9168  8216  7907  3102  6888  3714  7564 17006  9504   712  6048  6544  6761  4214  4298  5325
[579]  8804

Create a map

```
   hexagons_with_lines$component <- factor(hexagons_with_lines$component)
   ggplot() +
     geom_sf(data = hexagons_with_lines, aes(fill = component), color = NA) +  # Remove stroke
     scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
     theme_minimal() +
     labs(fill = "Component", title = "Map of Hexagons with Line Components")
```

Results

[Results for discrete values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtM6H.png)

Comment: The issue is that you `component` column contains a lot of categories. The result is a huge legend that squeezes the map together. To make you map visible add `+ guides(fill = "none")`. Also note that most or all Brewer color palettes  provide only a limited number of colors. That's why most categories in the legend are shown with no color.